# Create a List with the same type that a class property

Tags: c#, list, generics

I want to create a list taking all the values that a property has in a list of certain class and add these values into another list whose type is the same than the class property.

Lets suppose I have the Book class:

```
public class Book{
    public int code;
    public string genre;
    public string author;
    public string synopsis;
}
```

Then, I have some method with a `List<Book> myList` containing some books and I want to populate a list of bookCodes which should be of the same type than Book's property code. I want not to change the declaration of the list of BookCodes `List<int> myBookCodes` if some day the `code` property is changed from `int` to `long` or `Guid`, for example.

I have tried things such as

```
var myBookCodes = new List<typeof(Books.code)>
```

But I get a "Type expected" error.

I have also tried to use reflection but I also got errors:

```
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo bookCodeProperty = typeof(Book).GetProperty("code");
Type bookCodeType = bookCodeProperty.PropertyType;

var myBookCodes = new List <>(bookCodeType)
```

But in this case the compiler complains "bookCodeType is a variable but it is used like a type".

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is easy... you just project the list and the type is taken care of for you:

```
List<Book> myList ...
var codesList = myList.Select(b => b.code).ToList();
```

> if some day the code property is changed from int to long or Guid

Then the code still works, and is now the new type.